# If A and B are correlated, what is the correlation between |A1 + A2| and |B1 + B2|?

Tags: correlation, random-variable, covariance, absolute-value

To preface, let random variables $X = A_1 + A_2$ and $Y = B_1 + B_2$. $A_1$ and $A_2$ are copies of $A \sim N(0, 1)$, and $B_1$ and $B_2$ are copies of $B \sim N(0, 1)$. In this situation, if $A$ and $B$ co-vary, and then $cor(X, Y) = cor(A, B)$.

But, if $X = |A_1 + A_2$| and $Y = |B_1 + B_2$|, and $cor(A, B) = 0.3$, then what is $cor(X, Y)$? Is there an analytical solution to this?

(For background, I'm trying to answer the question: if two columns of data are correlated, then how correlated are two-directional group-difference hypothesis tests on these data?)

Comment: The answer is no; but if you specify the *joint* distributions of $(A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2)$ then at least we know there will be a unique answer.  The difficulty is that the univariate Normality of these variables does not imply much about the distributions of $X$ or $Y.$